# How can i find out which subdomain is bringing majority of traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: tracking, subdomain, google-analytics

I have around 20 websites on 20 `sub-domains` , all are using same `Google analytics` `tracking code` for tracking hits.

One of the site i.e. `sub-domain` is getting lots of hits, i would like to know more about that `sub-domain` only. and that site only. .e.g. bounce rate of that site, avg. page-views., avg. time spent on that sub-domain.

How can i know something like that ?

i have already added Filter in `Google Analytics` to show `sub-domains` too in the reports.

e.g.

```
Filter Name : Add whole domain
Filter Type : Advanced
Field A -> Extract A : Hostname (.*)
Field B -> Extract B : Reuest URI (.*)
Output To -> Constructor : $A1$B1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog article I wrote that explains how to do this: http://blog.ostermiller.org/analytics-subdomain/   Here is the step by step guidance from the blog post:

1. Navigate to “Content”-> “Site Content” -> “All Pages”. 
   [image: Google Analytics All Pages Navigation]
2. Change the primary dimension to “Other” -> “Content” -> “Hostname”.  
   [image: Google Analytics Primary Dimension Host name]
    At this point the data table will show your best host names but the graph will still show total page views.
3. If you have more than 10 sub-domains, you may want to show more of them at once.  Only the number shown will be included in the graph. 
   [image: Google Analytics Show Rows]
4. Select the icon for “Motion Chart” above the graph on the right hand side instead of the currently selected icon for “Line Chart”.  ”Motion chart” is the icon with the three circles on it. (Don’t ask me why the line chart I want is under “motion chart” rather than “line chart.”) 
   [image]
5. Use the tabs on the top right of the graph and select the one with the line on it.  You will get the graph that you are looking for. 
   [image]
    Each of the lines on that graph represents a sub-domain so you can quickly compare how your sub-domains are doing over time.  The graph is interactive so you can mouse over it to see data and use the check boxes to the right to highlight rows.